# Installation Error: "cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'utilities.h' file not found"

Tags: r

I'd like to download an R package, "Mapper."

However, when I try to download I get the following (fatal) error:

```
####
#CODE
#####

devtools::install_github("peekxc/Mapper")

####
#ERROR CODE
###

gromov_hausdorff.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'utilities.h' file not found
#include "utilities.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [gromov_hausdorff.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Mapper
```

My question is, can this be resolved? Or is it because the files are no longer available to download?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

https://peekxc.github.io/Mapper/

Comment: https://github.com/peekxc/Mapper/issues/18

Comment: Hi @user20650. I get an invalid repo on that call. I wondered if you had a similar issue?

Comment: I didn't try. You could  trawl through the earlier [versions](https://github.com/peekxc/Mapper/commits/master/) to try to find one that works. But likely that will be going back several years and then this can open a can of worms in getting relevant versions of dependencies. The package is archived and so not supported any more, and if you can't get it installed  you could 1) look for another package or 2) spend the time in trying to fix what is broken in the current code